# Generate a PDF from an ASPX page

Tags: .net

1. I have a form with all the data, I need to generate the PDF. Also there are some attachments like word files.

   2. Is it also possible to embed the contents of the attachment in the PDF?

I am mainly looking for a solution for #2.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot embed Word files in to a PDF document, but you can embed a link if the location of the Word files is static.

This looks like a situation where Reporting Services would be ideal, as you can generate the report (which you are currently showing as data on a web page) and have it rendered as a PDF document. You can then either deliver the PDF as a document via the web page's Response stream, or have it embedded in the web page, or have it emailed as an attachment to a recipient. If you are running SQLServer (even the express version) then Reporting Services is a free component you can install.